# Проблемы "округления" в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика, числа, округление

Пишу программу, что складывает n цифр в дробной части числа.
При выполнение обнаружил странную деталь, а именно, что
**123.0023 - дробная часть 0023**, а
**12.0023 - дробная часть 002999999** и при округление **умножить на 10^n+1//1** получается 22.
Как избежать подобной ошибки, код прикреплю ниже

```
y = float(input())
m = ((y%1*10000))
#print(m, m//1)
m=int(m//1)
s = sum(map(int,str(m)))
print(s)
```

Comment: Работать со строкой...

Comment: https://0.30000000000000004.com/

Comment: Из решений - можно использовать модуль decimal )